# Downscale Videos in the photos app easily, from 4k to FHD

Tags: photos.app, video

My Mac Photos app shows large 4K videos taking up significant iCloud storage. I want to downscale them to 2K or FHD for space savings, but retain all other video information like metadata, HDR, and 60fps frame rate. Compressor seems too complex and creates larger files. Is there an easy, native-like way to downscale videos within the Photos app, or using another simple tool, while preserving everything except resolution (HDR, 60fps, metadata and so on)?